# ¿Cual es Importancia de las migraciones laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration

Estoy Recién Aprendiendo Laravel y Quiero saber porque usar las migraciones y no crear las tablas en la base de dato directamente , es necesario usar las migraciones en laravel o podria crear mis tablas y sus campos directamente en phpmyadmin.

Comment: Puedes crear la BD sin usar las migraciones de Laravel, mediante scripts SQL. Las migraciones son un mecanismo que te permite tener un historial de la evolución de la estructura de tu BD. La creación de las tablas, modificaciones, etc. quedan registradas mediante las migraciones, además si tu código está versionado, por ejemplo con Git, todo lo necesario para generar la base de datos de la aplicación queda registrado junto con la evolución de la misma. Las migraciones pueden ser revertidas y ejecutadas de nuevo si es necesario, por lo que es un mecanismo sencillo para *resetear* la BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las migraciones en Laravel tienen varias ventajas comparado con crear la estructura de la base de datos directamente:

- Permiten crear, hacer o deshacer modificaciones a las tablas, columas, índices desde una clase, sin tener que crear un script para conectarse o utilizar línea de comando o algún administrador para escribir las líneas necesarias.
- Simplifican la sintaxis, especialmente para quienes no están familiarizados con lo básico de MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.
- Aportan control de versiones de la base de datos, en vez de tener que modificar algún un archivo gigante con el código SQL, y si hubo algún error, es tan sencillo como hacer `migrate:rollback`.

---

No es necesario utilizar las migraciones de Laravel, pero es altamente recomendado, sería casi imposible para mí crear un proyecto con unas 150 tablas  sin las migraciones.

Puede crear las tablas y campos en phpmyadmin, aunque prefiero adminer, mucho más ligero y soporta varios motores.

Answer (score 0):

Tus migraciones son esencialmente un control de versiones de tu base de datos, mantienen el registro de como tu base de datos fue cambiando en el lapso de tiempo, las migraciones hacen fácil depurar tu aplicación o distribuirla a otra gente.

Si no usas migraciones, no habrá registro de la estructura de tu base de datos, a menos que guardes una copia de tu "schema". Con migraciones, instalas tu app, configuras tu conexión de la BD y después corres `php artisan migrate` para que tu base de datos esté instantáneamente lista.